# How to handle if statement along with and operator in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, nested

```
if instanceType == instance_type and operatingSystem == operating_system and tenancy == tenancy_db:
    sku_list.append(key)
```

In this if statement these variables, instanceType, operatingSystem and tenancy, are user input, how to handle not to check if any user input is None.

e.g. if instanceType is None, i would like to check

```
if operatingSystem == operating_system and tenancy == tenancy_db:
    sku_list.append(key)
```

e.g. if operatingSystem is None, i would like to check

```
if instanceType == instance_type and tenancy == tenancy_db:
    sku_list.append(key)
```

e.g. if both tenancy and instanceType is None, I would like to check:

```
if operatingSystem == operating_system:
    sku_list.append(key)
```

Simliarly, it depends on whether user input in None or something else, is there any other way to do this, or i have to implement nested if else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to declare a helper function:

```
equal_or_none = lambda x, y: x is None or x == y
if (
        equal_or_none(instanceType, instance_type) 
        and equal_or_none(operatingSystem, operating_system)
        and equal_or_none(tenancy, tenancy_db)):
    sku_list.append(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `or` operator which will treat `None` as false:

```
if (instanceType or instance_type) == instance_type and \
   (operatingSystem or operating_system) == operating_system and \
   (tenancy or tenancy_db) == tenancy_db:
    sku_list.append(key)
```